# I need to restart chrome to get work this extension. Why?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Manifest.json:

```
{
 "background_page": "background.html",
 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon-128.png"
 },
 "name": "testtt",
 "description": "testttttttt",
 "icons": {
     "16": "icon-16.png",
     "48": "icon-48.png",
     "128": "icon-128.png" },
 "permissions": [
     "tabs",
     "http://*/*",
     "https://*/*"
 ],
 "version": "0.1"
}
```

background.html:

```
<script>
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "bookmarklet.js"})
    });
</script>
```

bookmarklet.js:

```
alert("hello");
```

When I install this extension, the button in top-right side doesn't work. So I need to restar chrome to get it work. Why ?

Comment: is another version of the extension installed before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works like a charm on this end.

Though it should fail if you're clicking the button while you're on `chrome://...` pages. But you can fix `background.html` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        if(typeof(tab)!=='object' || tab.url.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome://')===0) return;
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "bookmarklet.js"})
    });
</script>
```

Tested 19.0.1084.46 (Official Build 135956) m

Comment: Possibly. Although they built this thing to be cross-platform. If there's nothing else in your extension and consoles all clear of red, you should file a bug at http://www.crbug.com.